# split() start with()

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит строку произвольной длины. Определить количество слов, которые начинаются на "о" в строке, введенной пользователем.

```
my_list = input('Enter Here: ')
print(my_list.split())
reseul = my_list.startswith('o')
print(f'{reseul}{len(my_list)}')
```

и дальше я потерялся

Comment: Метод `split` разбивает строку и **возвращает** список, но **не модифицирует** значение, на которую ссылается переменная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

startswith('o') возвращает true/false, а вовсе не фильтрует ваш лист. Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так

```
my_list = input('Enter Here: ')
# теперь отберем те слова, которые начинаются на о
reseul = [x for x in my_list.split()  if x.startswith('o')]
print(len(reseul))
```

возможно, надо `if x.lower().startswith('o')`, чтобы не зависеть от регистра

Comment: Обратите внимание на мой комментарий к вопросу. Сейчас ваш код считает число символов 'o'.

Comment: Спасибо, точно :(

Comment: правильно нужно подсчитать кол-во слов начинающихся на "o"
если с заглавной начинается можно написать "О" != "o"?

Comment: @RostislavPopov Ну да, просто сплит был в принте, и никак не влиял на результат. Цикл выполнялся по всем буквам вводимой строки

Comment: а я пытался упорно пихал туда startwith() и думал... а почему это не работает...

Comment: *если с заглавной начинается можно написать "О" != "o"* - вот это я не понял  :(

Comment: вопрос конечно глупый.... 
я так понимаю x fоr где х это переменная?

Comment: reseul = [x for x in my_list.split()  if x.startswith('o')]
при вводе заглавной 'О' возвращает значение =0

Comment: да, это внутренняя переменная цикла. в данном случае она будет получать все слова по очереди как знасениеэ

Comment: да, так и написано, вы обновите страничку :)

Comment: сори обновил)))

Answer (score 2):

Похожий вариант:

```
In [6]: user_input = "Oh my dear old Oak!"

In [7]: res = sum(word.lower().startswith("o") for word in user_input.split())

In [8]: print(res)
3
```